# AutoIT Access 2D Array Value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, autoit

How do I access a 2-d array I want to get the string dog from array position [3][3] and store it in a variable.  Here's my code

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <IE.au3>

Local $aTableData
Local $oIE = _IE_Example("table")
Local $oTables = _IETableGetCollection($oIE)
    For $oTable In $oTables
        If $oTable.id == "tableOne" Then
             $aTableData = _IETableWriteToArray($oTable)
             ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next

_ArrayDisplay($aTableData)

_IEQuit($oIE)
```

I thought something like this would work but it isn't

```
Local $oDog = $aTableData[3][3]
```

Comment: If you put this after @aTableData = _IETableWriteToArray($oTable) line: "ConsoleWrite ("number of elements: " & UBound($aTableData) & " " & $oTable.rows.length & @CRLF)" what are your counts?  Does the array actually have data in it?

Comment: Yes it returns this message in console: `number of elements: 6 6`

Comment: Your code should work...that is how you access an array in AutoIT...Is this code complete, or are you doing this in different functions?  Is your $oDog variable in a different function than your $oTable loop? It's a local variable.  If it's dropping out of scope, that's really the only thing that would effect it.

Comment: As an example, this works... It's basically the same thing you're doing.
Local $aTableData[2][2] = [["Test 0 0","Test 1 0"],["Test 0 1","Test 1,1"]]

Local $oDog = $aTableData[1][1] & @CRLF
ConsoleWrite($oDog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arrays**

> An Array is a variable containing series of data elements. Each
>   element in this variable can be accessed by an index number.

An example:

You want to store a series of characters: `"A", "U", "T", "O", "I", "T"` and `"3"`. You could use seven separate variables to do so, but using an Array is more efficient:

```
$aArray[0] = "A"
$aArray[1] = "U"
..etc..
$aArray[6] = "3"
```

To access a specific value in an Array, you use the index number:

```
$sString = $aArray[2]
```

This results in $sString containing the letter "T"

Your code:

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <IE.au3>

Local $aTableData
Local $oIE = _IE_Example("table")
Local $oTables = _IETableGetCollection($oIE)
    For $oTable In $oTables
        If $oTable.id == "tableOne" Then
             $aTableData = _IETableWriteToArray($oTable)
             ExitLoop
        EndIf
    Next

Local $oDog = $aTableData[3][3]
ConsoleWrite($oDog)

_ArrayDisplay($aTableData)

_IEQuit($oIE)
```

Comment: That works for the AutoIT sample code!  But I was just using that one as an example that was related to my actual problem.  In my actual problem (though I see the information in the cell of a table when `_ArrayDisplay($aTableData)` is executed, whenever I try to write it console, there isn't an output.

Comment: @dannytaki Then your problem is about console write and not the array usage itself. Try to use message box. If it can be shown in _ArrayDisplay then it surely can be accessed by using index. Why don't you make a error reproducer or post your script?

Comment: I added my script but I don't think it's going to be much use.  It requires that you have a `Amazon Seller` account otherwise you can't view the page.  I basically wanted the date of when my oldest older was placed.